# Not valid template file:frontend/base/default/template/catalog/category/page_header.phtml

Tags: template, local.xml, magento1.9.3

This is caused by the following piece of code in `app/design/frontend/smartwave/mango/layout/local.xml` (such a template in such a location does not really exist in any of the themes):

```
<action method="setTemplate"><template>catalog/category/page_header.phtml</template></action>
```

The only one existing template is located in `app/design/frontend/smartwave/mango/template/page/html/page_header.phtml`

Has someone any ideas on how to correct this issue, without causing any impact on the webshop?

The entire xml code looks like this:

```
 <catalog_category_default>
     <reference name="root">
         <action method="setTemplate" ifconfig="mango_settings/category/page_layout" condition="one_column"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
         <action method="setTemplate" ifconfig="mango_settings/category/page_layout" condition="two_column_left"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
         <action method="setTemplate" ifconfig="mango_settings/category/page_layout" condition="two_column_right"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
         <action method="setTemplate" ifconfig="mango_settings/category/page_layout" condition="three_column"><template>page/3columns.phtml</template></action>
     </reference>
     <reference name="page.header">
         <action method="setTemplate"><template>catalog/category/page_header.phtml</template></action>
     </reference>
     <reference name="left">
         <remove name="tags_popular"/>
         <remove name="catalog.leftnav"/>
         <block type="core/template" name="catalog.category" before="-" template="catalog/category/main_categories.phtml"/>
     </reference>
 </catalog_category_default>

 <catalog_category_layered>
     <reference name="root">
         <action method="setTemplate" ifconfig="mango_settings/category/page_layout" condition="one_column"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
         <action method="setTemplate" ifconfig="mango_settings/category/page_layout" condition="two_column_left"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
         <action method="setTemplate" ifconfig="mango_settings/category/page_layout" condition="two_column_right"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
         <action method="setTemplate" ifconfig="mango_settings/category/page_layout" condition="three_column"><template>page/3columns.phtml</template></action>
     </reference>
     <reference name="page.header">
         <action method="setTemplate"><template>catalog/category/page_header.phtml</template></action>
     </reference>
     <reference name="left">
         <remove name="tags_popular"/>
         <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.category" before="-" template="catalog/category/category_nav.phtml"/>
         <reference name="catalog.leftnav">
             <action method="unsetChild"><child>category_filter</child></action>
         </reference>
     </reference>
 </catalog_category_layered>
```

Comment: could you share entire block function xml code

Comment: @Venkat i shared it already

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that content of catalog/category/page_header.phtml and page/html/page_header.phtml is the same, you can change the line to:

```
<action method="setTemplate"><template>page/html/page_header.phtml</template></action>
```

But since this issue is specific to a theme (Mango theme), it's better to contact the author:

https://themeforest.net/user/p-themes

https://themeforest.net/item/mango-responsive-magento-theme/11629375/comments?page=12